# ubuntu pm2 command to run node-express site

Tags: javascript, node.js, ubuntu-14.04, pm2

If I run my node-express site by hand it works great.

`sudo node bin/www`

But my other sites are launched and spawn via pm2.

With pm2 I just setup the node startup site.js file and executable and just run `./site.js`
So pm2 just has to run `./site.js`

But this is the first node-express site I've ever tried to run using pm2.

So what I'm not getting is how to make it so pm2 can run the command `node bin/www`.

I've tried by making the `bin/www` file executable.  And it has the same first line in the file `#!/usr/bin/env node`  But pm2 just will not run it.  When I try pm2 echos --help to the console because it fails to interpret the command `sudo pm2 node bin/www`

How do you get pm2 to run such a command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend adding a [process file](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/) to your project. Here is something super basic just to give you an idea...

```
// -- bin/www/ecosystem.config.js
module.exports = {
  apps: [{
    name: 'app',
    script: 'site.js'
  }]
};
```

Then you can  run `sudo pm2 start bin/www/ecosystem.config.js`. Surely you'll find having this dedicated source of configuration handy for having later on as well should you need to fine-tune anything.

Comment: I like this.  Just a couple of things.  `www` is a FILE in the bin folder.  It is the file node-express uses to configure the site and then launch the app.js file in the folder parent to `bin`.  To run `node bin\www` I have to be in the parent folder; where app.js resides.  `bin\www` is where you app.set('port',...) & app.listen(); where app = require('.../app');`

Comment: So if I create a process file it would be `site.config.js` in the parent folder?  And `script:` would then point to 'bin\www`?

Comment: Wow.  Really batting a 100.  executing `sudo pm2 ecosystem` returns `command not recognized`